# Python how to read text file with different rows for columns?

Tags: python

I am trying to read a comma separated text file with following format:

```
name10,value10,name20,value20,name30,value30
n10,v10,n20,v20,n30,v30
n11,v11,n21,v21,n31,v31
n12,v12,n22,v22,n32,v32
,,n23,v23,n33,v33
,,n24,v24,,
```

`namex` and `valuex` go together.  But each pair of (`namex` , `valuex`) has different number of rows and I want to store this pair of columns in a dictionary (for further processing). Any suggestions how to do that?

Comment: use pandas `read_fwf`

Comment: It depends on the format and delimiters. Is this file always strictly aligned with the first row? What bout comma or tab separated files?

Comment: @JanStránský updated question. This is comma separated file

Comment: so please add commas to the content example

Comment: how can you store the pairs of columns in a dictionary for processing when multiple keys could be `None` since columns are missing multiple values? or are you just discarding those

Comment: @gold_cy well, not exactly. That would be column by column. Given 2 cols, I can get `{n10:v10, n11:v11, ...}` etc.

Comment: actually no, take a look at your data, n10 and v10 have two rows missing which would be a key of None for each

Comment: you show data without comma - show real data from file. You can open it in any text editor and copy it.

Comment: when you split a line like `,,n24,v24,,` you get a list with the same length as any full row, just with some empty strings. I don't see a problem.

Comment: @ewr3243 please provide also **full** expected output

Comment: in your file every column has the same number of rows - but some cells are empty - and you shouldn't have problem to read it with `read_csv()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.read_fwf('file.csv', colspecs='infer', skip=0, trim_ws=True)
for i in df1.values:
    ...
```